# VBA, Excel extract email body multiple lines into excel cells

Tags: excel, vba, split

I have button that extracts emails body into excel columns(code below),
My problem is that "Issue description:" sometimes is more than one line and then next column where "Nav error No:" should be, is next line from the issue description.

Here is sample of emails the this inbox will receive:

```
Platform: Nav 
Department: HR 
Site: Thailand 
Process: Test 
Area: Purchase Orders 
Issue description: This is only test 
Nav error No.: Error test
```

Code:

```
For Each olItem In olItems
    rCount = rCount + 1
    ws.Range("A" & rCount).Value = olItem.ReceivedTime
    ws.Range("B" & rCount).Value = olItem.SenderName
    ws.Range("C" & rCount).Value = olItem.Subject

    arrayLines = Split(olItem.Body, vbCrLf)
    ws.Range("D" & rCount).Value = Split(arrayLines(0), ": ")(1)  '<--- Platform
    ws.Range("E" & rCount).Value = Split(arrayLines(1), ": ")(1)  '<--- Department
    ws.Range("F" & rCount).Value = Split(arrayLines(2), ": ")(1)  '<--- Site
    ws.Range("G" & rCount).Value = Split(arrayLines(3), ": ")(1)  '<--- Process
    ws.Range("H" & rCount).Value = Split(arrayLines(4), ": ")(1)  '<--- Area
    ws.Range("I" & rCount).Value = Split(arrayLines(5), ": ")(1)  '<--- Issue description

    If arrayLines(6) = "" Then
        ws.Range("J" & rCount).Value = "N/A"  '<--- Nav error empty
    Else
        ws.Range("J" & rCount).Value = Split(arrayLines(6), ": ")(1)  '<--- Nav error message
    End If

Next olItem
```

I wanted to add to array full length of issue description before moving onto the next column which is nav error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it well, you know that the description you're looking for is contained between the string `Issue description:` and sometimes the string `Nav error No.:` which may or may not be there.

If that's always the case, then you can simply extract your description by splitting the whole mail body by the string `Issue description:`, then taking the part 1 and splitting by the string `Nav error No.:`, and getting the element `0`.

Basically that would be:

```
IssueDescription = Split(Split(olItem.Body, "Issue description: ")(1), "Nav error No.:")(0)
```

The variable `IssueDescription` now contains the whole description, whether it is on one line or multiple lines. If you want to print it in a single cell (hence you don't want the line breaks), you can just replace them with a space:

```
IssueDescription = Replace(IssueDescription, vbCrLf, " ")
ws.Range("I" & rCount).Value = IssueDescription
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response this is exactly what I was looking for. Problem solved :)

Comment: @PawelG if it worked, don't forget to accept the answer so the question will be closed.